# Faster way to perform user authentication using database functions

Tags: postgresql, authentication, password-encryption, sql-execution-plan

Is there a faster way to secure authenticate users using database functions ?
crypt() function seems took a lot of time.

Table:

```
id (bigserial) pkey
username (text) indexed
password (text) indexed [password is the hash: crypt('12345678', gen_salt('bf', 8))]
```

Plain tests:

```
test_db=# explain analyze SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = 1 AND password='12345678' LIMIT 1;
                                                                QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using users_idx_password01 on users  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (password = '12345678'::text)
         Filter: (id = 1)
 Total runtime: 0.037 ms
(5 rows)
```

Crypt() tests:

```
test_db=# explain analyze SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = 1 AND password=(crypt('12345678',password)) LIMIT 1;
                                                           QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=7.534..7.534 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=7.534..7.534 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id = 1)
         Filter: (password = crypt('12345678'::text, password))
 Total runtime: 7.550 ms
(5 rows)
```

Comment: By design, no.  Slowness is a feature, not a bug.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6364778/239394.  Besides, you're talking about a few milliseconds of difference per query, which one user is not necessarily going to notice.  Yes, it could add up in a system with many simultaneous login attempts (which could contribute to a denial-of-service attack, for example), but speeding up the hash is not the way to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, you correctly address the problem: every request need to be authenticated and with moderated concurrency (200 req/sec) the server become unresponsive. At that point I'm thinking to upgrade and splitting the hardware. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure about how postgres handles such a query, but it seem to me, that the crypt function is executed for every row. When you consider using an appropriate password hash function wich is slow on purpose, such queries will become slower with every row.

The way to handle such queries is, to search only for the user and afterwards verify the password hash:

```
SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = "carfield"
```

Afterwards you test the found password hash in your code. This also allows to handle unique salts for each password, which is a must have. Appropriate hash functions are BCrypt, PBKDF2 or SCrypt, all of them have a cost factor. Often the programming environment already offers functions, this is an example in PHP:

```
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

Comment: Thanks! average 33% faster. After some investigation seems that the crypt() function is not executed for every record, it is how postgres/pgcrypto library handle the call which is slower than php implementation. I erroneously thought that let the DB manage authentication was more robust/fast.

Comment: @DPZ - Interesting, yes PHP has a native implementation of BCrypt with the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. A fast implementation allows to increase the cost factor which is of course good for security.